# in what case getInstance will return null and how in multithreaded environments

Tags: java

```
public class UnsafeLazyInitialization {
    private static Resource resource;

    public static Resource getInstance() {
        if (resource == null) //1
            resource = new Resource();  //2
        return resource; //3
    }
}
```

1. is it possible that **get Instance return null**  if yes kindly help me out to understand why and how ?

Comment: No, it won't return null. If you call it from multiple threads, it might create more than one instance of `Resource`, but it wouldn't return null.

Comment: That would only happen if Thread1 is right before //3 and Thread 2 resets resource to null. But considering the given code, only - it won't.

Comment: in some website i read that  red write reordering concepet of jvm  can cause to written NULL

Answer (score 0):

`getInstance()` will never return `null`.

The danger of this implementation is different: there is no guarantee that `getInstance()` will return only one instance. In other words, your singleton is not really a singleton.